how to rename a worksheet tab based on cell value formatted to **/**/**
I wish to be able to copy a worksheet "ABACUS" and then paste it as new worksheet in the workbook, but as "W.E.**.**.**" the date coming from C1 in "ABACUS" which has to be formatted to **/**/** I have so far,
Public Sub CopySheetAndRenamePredefined()

       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       Dim ws As Worksheet
       Dim response As String
       For Each ws In Sheets
        If ws.Range("B2") <> "" And ws.Range("C2") = "" Then
        Do
            response = InputBox("Input date in format **/**/**")
            If response <> "" Then
            ws.Range("C2") = response
            Exit Do
            ElseIf response = "" Then
            MsgBox ("You must enter date in format **/**/**")

        Else: Exit Do
        End If
      Loop
    
      End If
      Next ws
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
      Dim WKend
      Dim arr As Variant
      Dim writerow As Long
    
       
    
     'copy overtime sunday
     With Sheets("ABACUS")
     WKend = .Range("M2").Value2
     arr = .Range("AI21:AI33").Value
     End With

     With Sheets("OVERTIME")
     ' last used row in column B plus 1
    
     writerow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A2") = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yy")
    .Range("A" & writerow) = WKend
    .Range("B" & writerow).Resize(, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
     End With
   
    'copy overtime monday
    With Sheets("ABACUS")
    WKend = .Range("AC2").Value2
    arr = .Range("AK21:AK32").Value
    End With

    With Sheets("OVERTIME")
    ' last used row in column B plus 1
    writerow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A" & writerow) = WKend
    .Range("B" & writerow).Resize(, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    End With

    'copy overtime tuesday
    With Sheets("ABACUS")
    WKend = .Range("AS2").Value2
    arr = .Range("AM21:AM32").Value
    End With

    With Sheets("OVERTIME")
    ' last used row in column B plus 1
    writerow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A" & writerow) = WKend
    .Range("B" & writerow).Resize(, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    End With

    'copy overtime wednesday
    With Sheets("ABACUS")
    WKend = .Range("BI2").Value2
    arr = .Range("AO21:AO32").Value
    End With

    With Sheets("OVERTIME")
    ' last used row in column B plus 1
    writerow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A" & writerow) = WKend
    .Range("B" & writerow).Resize(, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    End With

    'copy overtime thursday
    With Sheets("ABACUS")
    WKend = .Range("BY2").Value2
    arr = .Range("AQ21:AQ32").Value
    End With

    With Sheets("OVERTIME")
    ' last used row in column B plus 1
    writerow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A" & writerow) = WKend
    .Range("B" & writerow).Resize(, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    End With

    'copy overtime friday
    With Sheets("ABACUS")
    WKend = .Range("CO2").Value2
    arr = .Range("AS21:AS32").Value
    End With

    With Sheets("OVERTIME")
    ' last used row in column B plus 1
     writerow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A" & writerow) = WKend
    .Range("B" & writerow).Resize(, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    End With

    'copy  overtime saturday
    With Sheets("ABACUS")
    WKend = .Range("DE2").Value2
    arr = .Range("AU21:AU32").Value
    End With

    With Sheets("OVERTIME")
    ' last used row in column B plus 1
    writerow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A" & writerow) = WKend
    .Range("B" & writerow).Resize(, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    End With
   
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets("OVERTIME")
  
    On Error Resume Next

    ws.Name = Format(CDate(ws.Range("B2").Value), "DD.MM.YY")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "W.E." & Range("C1").Value
  
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 2").Delete
    Worksheets("ABACUS").Activate
    Range("D5:DK17").ClearContents
    Range("C2").ClearContents
    Range("BP22:CE33").ClearContents
    Range("E3,G3,I3,K3,M3,O3,Q3,S3,U3,W3,Y3,AA3,AC3,AE3,AG3,
    AI3,AK3,AM3,AO3,AQ3,AS3,AU3,AW3,AY3,BA3,BC3,BE3,BG3,BI3,BK3,BM3,BO3").ClearContents
    Range("BQ3,BS3,BU3,BW3,BY3,CA3,CC3,CE3,CG3,CI3,CK3,CM3,CO3,CQ3,
    CS3,CU3,CW3,CY3,DA3,DC3,DE3,DG3,DI3,DK3").ClearContents
    [B25] = Range("DM2").Value
    [B26] = Range("DM2").Value
    [B27] = Range("DM2").Value
    [B28] = Range("DM2").Value
    [B29] = Range("DM2").Value
    [B30] = Range("DM2").Value
    [B31] = Range("DM2").Value
    [B32] = Range("DM2").Value

 
    End Sub

When running the code it copies worksheet but pastes it and names it as ABACUS(2)
I'm expecting a name tab of W.E.**.**.**

What happened if you remove the on error resume next? Have you checked if Format(CDate( ...)returns a valid name?

You're naming two sheets there - ws (which sheet is that?) and Activesheet (the copy you just made).  Maybe take a look at that.
